# Mysql server cannot be started with specific configurations

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL configured in a separate DB server. And there was a high CPU usage initially. I am pasting the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` details here

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
```

No specific configurations for `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size`. Therefore it is 128 M

To resolve the high CPU usage issue, I have updated the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file by adding/ updating several configurations and then the server is not started anymore

```
query_cache_limit       = 16M
query_cache_type        = ON
query_cache_size        = 128M 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 9G
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
innodb_log_file_size = 1768M
thread_cache_size       = 8
max_heap_table_size = 536870912
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
myisam-recover = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
```

Here, the configurations are added by referring the MySQL documents and the configurations and the configurations satisfies the following equation as well

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = n times * (innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances)
```

[mysql-documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html)

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't tell us what MySQL tells you about why it won't start. Why do you think that increasing allowed memory allocation size would resolve high CPU use? Observe, analyze, take action. What did you observe and what did your analysis tell you? From what you wrote, we can only try to guess why your MySQL won't start.

Comment: Check your MySQL error log, it may have some clues about why it wouldn't start. Look especially for the word "ERROR".

Comment: So we are supposed to GUESS how much RAM is on the server?  How much RAM is available? Post your complete A) my.cnf rather than just parts of the file, and the LAST 400 lines of your error log.  Please.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM?

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size   -- about 70% or RAM if you have more than 4GB of RAM
max_heap_table_size       -- 1% of RAM
query_cache_size          -- 0 or 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances  -- 1 per GB of buffer_pool
max_connections           -- 100 until you have a clear need for more
```